# What do I need to change in the binding to work with the desired property in ListBox.ItemTemplate for showing Icon pics?

Tags: xaml

I am writing small WPF program for myself. Its find all duplicates in a directory.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP00T.jpg)

**I've a problem:** I want to show the icon for every type of file. But by **binding the mechanism searching the "Ico" property in "FileConsist" instead of "ListForViewDuplicates"** and my icons column stays empty. It should be to the left of the "Type" column.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRelL.jpg)

1. I've UserControl with `DataContext="{Binding DuplicatesViewModel}.`
2. "DuplicatesViewModel" property (Collection of all collections - result of all my program. Use it for View):
   `public ObservableCollection<ListForViewDuplicates> CollectionForDuplicatesView { get; set; }`
3. "ListForViewDuplicates" properties (Single collection for each duplicates):

```
        public string NameDuplicates { get; set; }
        public Bitmap Ico { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<FileConsist> FullInfoFiles { get; set; }
```

4. "FileConsist" peoperties (This is clean Model - MVVM):

```
public class FileConsist
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public string FileExtension { get; set; }
        public double FileSize { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTimeCreate { get; set; } ...
...}
```

XAML "sees" the NameDuplicates proprty from "ListForViewDuplicates", but the Ico property is not:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="DuplicatesFinder_v4.Views.DuplicatesView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DuplicatesFinder_v4.Views"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:ImageConverter x:Key="IconConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <ListBox BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionForDuplicatesView}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="0,0,0,5">
                        <ListView
                            Name="WholeList"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding FullInfoFiles}"
                            SelectionMode="Multiple">
                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#2b4566" />
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderStyle}">
                                    <GridViewColumn
                                        Width="420"
                                        Header="{Binding NameDuplicates}"
                                        HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeadRedGridView}">

                                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <CheckBox
                                                    Content="{Binding FilePath}"
                                                    FontSize="14"
                                                    Foreground="#2b4566"
                                                    IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedInView}"
                                                    ListView.IsSelected="True" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn>

                                    <GridViewColumn Width="20">
                                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Image
                                                    Width="12"
                                                    Height="12"
                                                    Source="{Binding Path=Ico, Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}}" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn>
                                    <GridViewColumn Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileExtension}">Type</GridViewColumn>
                                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileSize}">Size, kb</GridViewColumn>
                                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateTimeCreateString}">Creation Date</GridViewColumn>
                                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateTimeModifiedString}">Modified Date</GridViewColumn>
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I've already tried to do the same with Icon, creating a new simple program without a template. Just the icon pic and File name. It is all work (Converter, method for getting Bitmap for the icon). So, it's something wrong with my logic in XAML. What do I have to do to solve my problem? Help me please.